# Mongodb+Mongoose: $redact to handle document access

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

From official mongodb documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/

I'm using **$redact** operator to filter documents by access-tags. **In the official guide it uses userAccess static array** to filter documents. In my code **I would you use a dynamic array based on the owner field value**.

```
    Data.aggregate([
     { $match: {owner: {$in: followings}}},
     { $redact:
         {
            $cond:
               {
                 if: { $gt: [ { $size: { $setIntersection: [ "$circles", user.followers.id("$owner").circles ] } }, 0 ] },
                 then: "$$DESCEND",
                 else: "$$PRUNE"
               }
         }
     }
   ], function(err,result) {
        if(err)
            return next(err);

        console.log(result);

    });
```

How can I access to **owner** value with expression **user.followers.id("$owner").circles**?

Comment: You can't do that. The java script statement is evaluated before the aggregation code is executed on the server. This implies that, "$owner" will be treated a string literal and not be obtained from the document context, and passed on to the `id` function. The value obtained will be passed on to the server as part of the aggregation code to be executed. You could have an `array` of `circles` for all the possible values in the `followings` array before hand and pass it to the `$setIntersection` operator.

Comment: Then the only possible solution is application level filtering the result array in the callback?

Comment: Could you give an example of what a document looks like? Can you store the owners' `circles` in the document, and intersect that with the `circles`?

Comment: The example is with two collections:
1) collection of users with followers array. Each follower contains the follower _id and the circles where the current user is added.
2) collection of posts. Each post contains the post _id, the user owner _id and the circles with the post was shared.

For full documented example go there: https://github.com/jmikola/mongodb-docs/blob/master/draft/use-cases/social-networking-updates-and-profiles.txt